# How to declare factory methods with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
class Context {

}

class MyClass1 {
    constructor(context: Context, argv: number) {
        //do something with context
    }
}

class MyClass2 {
    constructor(context: Context, argv1: string, argv2: number) {
        // do something with context
    }
}

type ExcludeContext<T extends new (context: Context, ...argv: any) => any> =
    T extends new (context: Context, ...argv: infer P) => any ? P : never

type a = ExcludeContext<typeof MyClass1> // [number]
type b = ExcludeContext<typeof MyClass2> // [string, number]

class Factory {
    constructor(private context: Context) { }

    createObj(template: typeof MyClass1, ...argv: ExcludeContext<typeof MyClass1>) {
        return new template(this.context, ...argv)
    }
    createObj2<T extends (typeof MyClass1) | (typeof MyClass2)>(template: T, ...argv: ExcludeContext<T>) {
        // Oops,compiler prompt error for argv 
        // Expected 3 arguments, but got 1 or more.
        // An argument for 'argv' was not provided
        return new template(this.context, ...argv)
    }
}
```

I have many class that use contenxt for `constructor`.
However, context is designed to passed from Factory so that these class should created by Factory.
I want to implement a simple generic method to create objs.
That's OK for `createObj` but it went wrong when I try to declare a generic method `createObj2`.
`template` was shown as `new (context:Context,argv1:never,argv2:number)=>MyClass1|MyClass2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional types that still have unresolved type parameters are usually not something TS tries to reason to much about. It is usually best to avoid using conditional types in the implementation of generic functions. If you must use them a type assertion will probably be needed (`return new template(this.context, ...argv as any)`).

However in this case, we can rewrite the function without any conditional types using constructor signatures and tuples in rest parameters:

```
class Factory {
  constructor(private context: Context) { }
  createObj<T extends MyClass1 | MyClass2, U extends any[]>(template: new (context: Context, ...args: U) => T, ...argv: U) {
    return new template(this.context, ...argv)
  }
}


let f = new Factory(new Context());
f.createObj(MyClass2, "A", 1)
f.createObj(MyClass1, 1)
f.createObj(MyClass1, "A") // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-g96vCwP8GQy4lwKkDZMpNP8nQh3WiACIAIJV6K0COF0nktBU6llvl0BtNout1DtztdbvQWtVrITdKsXBAA)